# Translate C program to MIPS, using stack (int to 32 bits)

Tags: c, assembly, mips, translate

So I am studying MIPS and I need to translate this C program in MIPS, but I don't know to use stack. I've written the program without using the stack, but procedures apparently use it. Can someone help me? 
This is the C code:

```
void bts(int n, char *s)
{ int i;
  for(i=0; i<32; ++i) if(n & (1<<i)) s[i]='1'; else s[i]='0';
  s[32]='\0';
}
void main()
{
 int x=259; char y[100]; bts(x,y); printf("%s\n",y);
}
```

And this is my MIPS program. All I need to do is put the values in stack but I don't get it how. If someone can modify the code would really help me.

```
.data
x: .space 4
y: .space 100
.text
main:

li $t0, 259

jal bts

#afisare
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, y
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
#end_main

bts:
li $t1, 0 #i=t1
li $t2, 32

for:
beq $t1, $t2, exit 
#t3=masca (1<<i)
li $t3, 1 
sllv $t3, $t3, $t1
#t4=n&(1<<i)
and $t4, $t0, $t3  
   beq $t4, $zero, bit0 
         li $t4, '1'
         sb $t4, y($t1)
         j cond1

   bit0: li $t4, '0'
     sb $t4, y($t1)

     cond1: addi $t1, $t1, 1
        j for
#end_for

exit: jr $ra
```

#end_bts

Comment: Allocate space by subtracting from `$sp`. Use said space. Free it by adding the amount back.

Comment: Why don't you [look at how the compilers actually compile your code](https://godbolt.org/z/TfSZ7L)? On MIPS, the usual [calling convention](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180417-00/?p=98525) is to pass arguments 1-4 in $4-$7, and arguments $5 onwards on the stack. The example I provided passes 4 dummy arguments, so that you can observe how to pass arguments on the stack. You also see how the memory is allocated for the `y` buffer by subtracting from the stack pointer.

Comment: Are you allowed to optimize the code? If so, you can avoid a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: @EOF unfortunatelly no...this is my homework, but our professor doesn't teach us anything so I have to learn MIPS alone :)))). Sorry for my broken English btw. I tried to understand the stack and how tu use it but I really don't get it how am I suppose to put 32 bits in stack then take them and put them in y...I mean...it seems so unnecessary ...

Comment: @L.D. In that case, I recommend you start by finding out what ABI your professor expects you to use. It's quite unlikely for passing an argument in `$t0` to be correct, also you're not passing the second argument to `bts()`.

Comment: @EOF how would you write the code to mips?